# How to search by digit in DateTime column using Odata Queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, odata

I have a table containing `DateTime` column (ModifiedDate) along with other fields. I have implemented server side paging and searching using odata.
If in search box i enter Digits (Example 01) then I need to retrieve all the rows in the table containing 01 as either date, Month or year.
OR if i give 01/ then it should search rows containing 01 as date.
What Odata Query should i use?

I was trying below Query but it gives me error saying ModifiedDate is Datetime not string so you cannot use contains.

http://localhost:3039/api/QueueApi/Get?$filter=contains(FirstName,'searchValue') or contains(ModifiedDate,'searchValue')

Answer (score 0):

**contains** only works with strings

You need to build a URI like

$filter=year(ModifiedDate) eq 1 or month(ModifiedDate) eq 1 or day(ModifiedDate) eq 1

note that these functions only work with integer values so you will need to remove characters like /